# How can I get partial participation of both entities in 1:1 relationship

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship, one-to-one

I've taken a relationship between a `Subject` and a `Lecturer` as a concrete example. That means that there is a `subject` that **may** be provided by only **one** `lecturer` and a `lecturer` that **may** provide only **one** `subject`. How can I get partial participation of both entities in 1:1 relationship in Relational Data Model (Logical Data Model)? How much tables do I need and how to build them? I'm got stuck.

Comment: What do you mean by partial participation?

Comment: @WesH As far as I know that means that an entity may participate in the relationship, but also may not participate. That corresponds to [0;1] multiplicity. From the other hand, total participation stands for [1;1] relation.(Upper bound is 1 because that corresponds for my question)

Comment: It sounds like you're mixing the entities and an instance (or record) of the entity.  A relationship is between two entities.  The cardinality describes the relationship from EntityA to EntityB, which is true for every instance of EntityA.  0:1 would mean that for every EntityA, there can be 0 or at most 1 related instance of EntityB.  B may have a different cardinality relationship with A, it does not have to be 0:1.  1:1 would mean that every EntityA is related to one and only one EntityB.  As before, EntityB could have the same or different cardinality back to EntityA.

Comment: @WesH the example that I've suggested has cardinalities [0:1] to [0:1] exactly. Thanks you for correction about mixing up things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edited

**First Approach**: This approach is based on **Data Modeling**:

Condition 1 (c1): There is **a** `subject` that may be provided by **only one** `lecturer`

Condition 2 (c2): and **a** `lecturer` that may provide **only one** `subject`.

To apply c1: you have two options:

1. transfer P.K of `lecturer` as F.K to `subject`. It can be `NULL` too. But if a `subject` provided by only one `lecturer`, put `lecturer`'s P.K in it. This option has **Nullification**.
2. to avoid Nullification, make another table `subject_lecturer` (only for using this condition) with two columns (`subject_id` and `lecturer_id`). They are F.Ks from their original tables (`subject` and `lecturer`). In this new table you only save **a subject that may be provided by only one `lecturer`**. So you should make `subject_id` as UNIQUE. So you can insert only one subject into this table.

To apply c2: you have the similar options as c1.

1. same as option 1 in c1.
2. same as option 2 in c1. But you should make another table (`lecturer_subject`) for this. In this new table you should make `lecturer_id` as UNIQUE. So you can insert only one lecturer into this table.

**Can we merge them (`subject_lecturer` , `lecturer_subject`):** 
Based on Data Modeling concepts (ER) you have different types of data in c1 and c2.

**Second Approach**: **However**, there is a solutions to merge them.

Merge them into one table (`subject_lecturer_allinone`) and use a `type` column that **only** can be `0` for c1 records `1` for c2 records.

```
subject_lecturer_allinone
    subject_id is F.K and refers to Subject table
    lecturer_id is F.K and refers to lecturer table
    type : only can be 0 (for c1 records) and 1 (for c2 records)
```

We should use 2 UNIQUE constraints to handle coming data.

```
(lecturer_id , type) when the value of type is 1
(subject_id , type ) when the value of type is 0
```

This is not ER solution and you should write some Functions or Triggers to handle it.

Comment: Thanks you for respond. Can I somehow avoid NULLs in my table?

Comment: what does **make together as UNIQUE** means? I understand this like a complex PK of the third table `Third_table(Lecturer_id(PK), Subject_id(PK), ...)`, in this case there may exist a situation when one subject could be provided by a lot of lecturers: `third_table(01, 01,....)` and `third_table(02, 01,...) will stand as two unique records. But I guess I am wrong.